# Envio de email C# Erro Invalid HELO name

Tags: c#

Minha duvida é a seguinte, no sistema que desenvolvo tem opção de enviar email direto do sistema, como por exemplo email da NFe e arquivos. eu utilizo a seguinte configuração para enviar o email.

```
MailMessage mensagemEmail = new MailMessage();

mensagemEmail.To.Add("emailcliente@email.com.br");

mensagemEmail.From = new MailAddress("emailempresa@email.com.br", "Nome     Empresa");
mensagemEmail.Subject = Assunto;
mensagemEmail.Body = "<pre>" + Mensagem + "</pre>";

mensagemEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = mail.dominio.com.br;
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = False;

//Email do dominio hostgator
//utilizo essa configuração em todos os clientes
string Usuario = "Emailpadrao@email.com.br";
string Senha = "Senha";

NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(Usuario, Senha);
client.Credentials = cred;
client.Send(mensagemEmail);
```

Só que o que acontece, na maioria dos clientes funciona normalmente mas em alguns tive problema de retornar este erro(Invalid HELO name (See RFC5321 4.1.1.1)).

Em alguns testes que fiz para tentar solucionar, se eu colocar esta mesma configuração no outlook 2010 e fazer aquele teste de envio dele resolve o problema no sistema também.

Preciso descobrir o que o outlook muda na configuração do windows para liberar o envio de email.

Alguém tem alguma idéia???

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde amigo,
O que eu descobri referente a esse erro causado, é que tem a ver com o SMTP...
Pois andei pesquisando sobre esse RFC e ele é referente ao Simples Mail Tranfer Protocol (SMTP)
Agora tem que ver se realmente sua configuração está correta com a do Outlook...

Fonte: https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5617

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizo nos meus projetos (uso o email para isso) e meu código fica assim, adapte para a sua necessidade e teste aí:

Verifique se necessita de SSL e default Credentials tbm.

```
public static void Send(Email email)
{
    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
    {
        smtp.Host = email.Host;
        smtp.Port = email.Port;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(email.AddressFrom, email.Password);
        using (var mail = new MailMessage())
        {
            mail.From = new MailAddress(email.AddressFrom);
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.AddressTo));
            mail.Subject = email.Subject;
            mail.Body = email.Message;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
    }
}
```

Segue abaixo model do Email para te ajudar se quiser utilizar esse exemplo:

```
public class Email
{
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string AddressFrom { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string AddressTo { get; set; }
}
```